# How to Auto Update Table HTML Data read data from json file? I block with it problem

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to auto update the html table that reads a json file
This json updates the information every 5 seconds so instead of refreshing the web, I want it to only update the table data, but I can't, I've been reading and testing for 3 days and I can't.

Can someone help me with this?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>DATOS</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inc/js/tablefilter_all_min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="test/css" href="css/filtergrid.css">

<head>
<body>
<table id="table" class=" TF"cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
<thead>
        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
            <th>VDN</th>
            <th>VDN</th>
        <th>INPROGRESS-ATAGENT</th>
            <th>OLDESTCALL</th>
        <th>AVG_ANSWER_SPEED</th>
        <th>ABNCALLS</th>
        <th>AVG_ABANDON_TIME</th>
        <th>ACDCALLS</th>
        <th>AVG_ACD_TALK_TIME</th>
        <th>ACTIVECALLS</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<?php
$file = "report/vdn.json";
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

//var_dump($json);

foreach ($json as $row){
echo "<tr>";
//echo $row;
$parts = explode(',', $row);
foreach ($parts as $part){
    $aux = explode(':"', $part);
    $aux2 = $aux[1];
    $aux3 = str_replace('"','',$aux2);
    echo "<td><center>$aux3</center></td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
//var_dump($parts);
}
//echo "</table>";


?>
</table>
</body>
<script>
var table2_Props = {
    col_0: "select",
    col_1: "select",
    col_2: "select",
    col_3: "select",
    col_4: "select",
    col_5: "select",
    col_6: "select",
    col_7: "select",
    col_8: "select",
    col_9: "select",
    col_10: "select",

    display_all_text: " [ Mostrar Todo ] ",
    sort_select: true
};
var tf2 = setFilterGrid("table", table2_Props);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You should implement an API that returns the JSON. Then call that from JavaScript with AJAX and update the table.

Comment: As @Barmar stated, a front end connection to an API would be the best route here.  Not to mention the benefits of loading the page first, and using "loading" icons wherever you're waiting for data ..  Faster page paint is always preferable, even if you're waiting for data.

Comment: If you use a library like DataTables, it can process the JSON directly.